# Unable to set up Dynamic Links for Firebase Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I've followed documentation in order to set dynamic links
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains

1. My domain was already added to my hosting
2. So I went ahead to dynamic links and created custom prefix i.e. https://example.com/link
3. After that I added custom hosting configuration and deployed it

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "hosting",
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/link/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      } 
    ]
  }
```

4. Once deployed I added following key to my iOS projects .plist file

```
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
  <string>https://example.com/link</string>
</array>
```

Now I've cleaned my build, ran the app and sent myself a dynamic link. Url still uses firebases `page.link` structure. I'm not sure if there is something I'm doing wrong or am I misunderstanding what these custom domains mean?

Note: I am testing this through email link (passwordless) authentication, perhaps custom domain is just not applied there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Auth only supports custom Firebase Dynamic Links without custom paths.

So if your custom domain is `https://example.com/link`, it won't work. However, configuring `https://example.com` as the custom domain will work.

Comment: does that mean that there is no way to have your website hosted at https://example.com and also have auth with firebase dynamic link? If I push my website files and then try to create a dynamic link without a `/suffix` I get an error message saying there is a conflict because I'm already serving some content at that path? Even if I use a subdomain https://signin.example.com, I get the same error message.